# submit Crashlytics: Failed to upload binary - but it actually succeeds

Tags: ios, jenkins, crashlytics, google-fabric

When submitting our *.ipa file to Fabric/Crashlytics via the command line (both from our Jenkins pipeline and manually) we're [incorrectly] receiving a...

> Unable to submit build. Response code 0
>
> Failed to upload binary

...error. This is breaking our build pipeline by falsely reporting failure of this lane, but it actually uploads correctly.

I've tried submitting the build via our Fastlane lane as well as manually running the submit command from terminal on my own machine, resulting in identical results. I've also reached out to our network engineers to whitelist all traffic to and from all subdomains of *.fabric.io and *.crashlytics.com so no traffic should be blocked by our corporate firewall/proxy.

(from our project directory)

```
$ ./Frameworks/Crashlytics.framework/submit <redacted-api-key> <redacted-secret> -ipaPath '<path/to/project>/buildoutput/<app name> <version> (Beta).ipa' -debug YES
2019-05-14 15:34:35.499 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (18)
2019-05-14 15:34:35.502 submit Crashlytics: Path to IPA manually provided: /path/to/project/buildoutput/****** (Beta).ipa
2019-05-14 15:34:37.449 submit Crashlytics: Path To App: /var/folders/**/************/*/****** (Beta)/Payload/******.app
2019-05-14 15:34:51.583 submit Crashlytics: Submitting IPA at /var/folders/**/************/*/com.crashlytics.mac/distributions/******-****-****-****-******.ipa
2019-05-14 15:35:10.829 submit Crashlytics: Unable to submit build. Response code: 0
2019-05-14 15:35:10.906 submit Crashlytics: Failed to upload binary
```

The main issue here is that it's actually uploading the binary to Fabric for beta distribution just fine. It's just reporting back to me/Jenkins that it's failed.

Comment: Reach out to support(at)fabric(dot)io if you are still running into this issue.

Comment: We spoke via email back on 5/22-5/24 already @Chintan. Still having the issue, though haven't put much effort into troubleshooting it lately. I'm currently testing the Firebase App Distribution beta to see if we're having similar issues there. If not, we might just wait it out for that.

Comment: Great, in either case, reach out if needed and we'll get you unblocked!